# SyncFolderItems multiple mailbox

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I've a Windows service with impersonate autorisations.
This service already have streaming subscriptions (grouped by affinity) for each mailbox, which works fine (it receive the events).

What I want to do now is to handle the case when the service is not running. So, when the service start I need to check all mailboxes for "missed" items.

Do you know how to do that ?

For a single mailbox I can call (using syncstate)

```
exchangeService.SyncFolderItems
```

I've tested for a single mailbox and it also works fine.
But how to do that for a specific mailbox ? I didn't find any way to call `SyncFolderItems` with a mailbox argument.
The folder I'm monitoring may be a "custom" folder (i.e. specific name).

Answer (score 0):

> > What I want to do now is to handle the case when the service is not running. So, when the service start I need to check all mailboxes for "missed" items.

SyncFolderItems should work okay for that, like nearly everything in EWS it works in the context of a Mailbox folder. If your using EWS Impersonation you would just send through the normal impersonation headers on each SyncFolderItems call you should also set the x-anchormailbox header (other wise you might get a no CAS server type error on Office365) on your requests but unlike streaming notifications you don't need to worry about affinity because the SyncState essential acts as a watermark or replication state marker for the client.

> > I've tested for a single mailbox and it also works fine. But how to do that for a specific mailbox ? I didn't find any way to call SyncFolderItems with a mailbox argument. The folder I'm monitoring may be a "custom" folder (i.e. specific name).

This is a little unclear if you have custom folder then you would need to find the EWSId of that Folder first (using FindFolder) before making the SyncFolderItem Request if its a default folder (eg Inbox,SentItem etc) then just use the WellKnowFolder enumeration and you can use the FolderId overload to specify the Mailbox your accessing. But if your using EWS Impersonation that isn't important because the mailbox context is going to come from the credentials you are impersonating.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: In fact, depending on the application configuration I'll subscribe to inbox OR to a subfolder with a custom name. Do you mean the `FolderId` is unique on the exchange server ? I thought it was unique for the mailbox. So using the FolderId I don't need to specify the mailbox ? Thank you

Comment: More detail: I use impersonation i.e. I connect with a user X but I have to handle subscription to mailbox for user Y

Comment: Yes the FolderId is global unique in the Exchange Org see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx . If you have the EWSId you don't need the Mailbox name if your using the Distinguished FolderId you do. If your working with Custom folders you need to find that folders ewsId first by using FindFolders.

Comment: >>I use impersonation i.e. I connect with a user X but I have to handle subscription to mailbox for user Y

Simple answer here is that you need to Impersonate the Mailbox your trying to access or else you will only have the rights assigned to X.

Comment: Yes impersonation is working. Problem was using this with SyncFolderItem, but as you said the overload with FolderId should works fine.